# jsPDF full screen rendering when in reduced size screen

Tags: vue.js, jspdf, html2canvas

I am working on pdf exporting feature in Vue.js and wondering if it is possible to have jsPDF render the full screen size version of the pdf when I request exporting in reduced screen size.
Right now, exporting feature works find when I hit the "export" button in full screen. However, when I do it in reduced screen size, the pdf version is created according to the current screen size which leads to weird page breaks. I am very new to jsPDF and wondering if I could get some help.

in conclusion, I want same pdf to be created whether or not I am in full screen or smaller screen (not the display size but the screen size). I want the resulting pdf file to be the one created when requesting export in full screen size.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Here is my code:

```
downloadPDF() {
        const element = document.getElementById('pdf-content'); 
        html2canvas(element).then((canvas) => {
            const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            const pdf = new jsPDF();
            const imgProps = pdf.getImageProperties(imgData);
            const pdfWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
            const pdfHeight = (imgProps.height * pdfWidth) / imgProps.width;
            let currentPage = 0;
            const pageHeight = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
            while (currentPage < pdfHeight) {
            let newHeight = currentPage + pageHeight <= pdfHeight ? pageHeight : pdfHeight - currentPage;
            pdf.addPage();
            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, -currentPage, pdfWidth, imgProps.height / imgProps.width * pdfWidth, undefined, 'FAST');
            currentPage += newHeight;
            }
            pdf.deletePage(1);
            pdf.save('ScoutingReport.pdf');
        });
    }
```

I am super new so I tried multiple solutions such as using break-before to fix the paging issue but I think the pdf file should be uniform rather than have many versions with different layouts due to responsive web layout.

Comment: A simple solution is to create an exact copy of your element but with fixed width and height, and hiding it from the user.  You can hide it by placing it inside a div with style `width: 900, height: 0, position: 'absolute', zIndex: -999999, overflow: 'hidden'` (change the width accordingly). This way, the user will see the responsive element, and you'll print the fixed dimensions hidden one.